# Looping and summing values from a different tag values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a problem with my XSLT, the Totals in the summary just wont show up, can anyone help me with this.

I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Header>
    <Year>2019</Year>
    <Month>08</Month>
    <DocNumber>1</DocNumber>
    <Company>
      <Name>My Company</Name>
      <City>City</City>
      <Country>Country</Country>
    </Company>
    <Items>
      <Item>
        <Type>A</Type>
        <Name>Item 2</Name>
        <Amount>20</Amount>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Discount>3</Discount>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Type>B</Type>
        <Name>Item 3</Name>
        <Amount>40</Amount>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Discount>3</Discount>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Type>C</Type>
        <Name>Item 1</Name>
        <Amount>30</Amount>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Discount>4</Discount>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Header>
</Document>
```

And this XSLT 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="noDisplay" select="'|B|D|'" />

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Header" />
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header">
    <xsl:variable name="iTotQty" select ="sum(Items/Item/Quantity)" />
    <xsl:variable name="iTotAmt" select ="sum(Items/Item/Amount)" />
    <xsl:variable name="iTotDisc" select ="sum(Items/Item/Discount)" />
    <Summary>
      <xsl:attribute name="Year">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Year" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Month">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Month" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="DocNumber" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="DocNumber" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="DocNumber" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="DocNumber" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="TotalQty">
        <xsl:value-of select ="$iTotQty" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="TotalAmt">
        <xsl:value-of select ="$iTotAmt" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="TotalDisc">
        <xsl:value-of select ="$iTotDisc" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Items/Item" />
    </Summary>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Items/Item">
    <xsl:variable name="bNoDisplay" select ="contains($noDisplay, concat('|', Type, '|'))" />
    <Item>
      <xsl:attribute name="Type">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Type" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Name" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:if test ="not($bNoDisplay)">
        <xsl:attribute name="Qty">
          <xsl:value-of select ="Quantity" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Amt">
          <xsl:value-of select ="Amount" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Disc">
          <xsl:value-of select ="Discount" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results in this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Summary Year="2019" Month="08" Number="1" TotalQty="5" TotalAmt="90" TotalDisc="10">
    <Item Type="A" Name="Item 2" Qty="2" Amt="20" Disc="3" />
    <Item Type="B" Name="Item 3" />
    <Item Type="C" Name="Item 1" Qty="2" Amt="30" Disc="4" />
  </Summary>
</Root>
```

The condition for the summary is that it should only sum up all of the Data (Qty, Amount and Discount) that are displayed in the Items, if it is not displayed it should not be part of the sum and if the Data (Qty, Amount and Discount) doesn't contain anything at all or resulted to 0 then should not be displayed

I can only use XSLT 1.0 so can anyone correct my stylesheet, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following stylesheet, minimized to address the problem presented in your **edited** question:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="noDisplay" select="'|B|D|'" />

<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Header" />
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Header">
    <xsl:variable name="displayed-items" select="Items/Item[not(contains($noDisplay, concat('|', Type, '|')))]" />
    <Summary Year="{Year}" Month="{Month}" Number="{DocNumber}" TotalQty="{sum($displayed-items/Quantity)}" TotalAmt="{sum($displayed-items/Amount)}" TotalDisc="{sum($displayed-items/Discount)}">
        <!-- omitted -->
    </Summary>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML example, the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Summary Year="2019" Month="08" Number="1" TotalQty="4" TotalAmt="50" TotalDisc="7"/>
</Root>
```

Comment: HI Michael, I edited my samples seems i got confused with my result when I posted last night, the Header should be the only child of the Document as well as in the result, the Summary should be the only child of Root, so the problem is the total is always summing it as a whole and not removing the hidden amounts in the Total

Comment: @zyberjock This is a completely new question, totally different from what I have originally answered. You should have posted it as a new question instead of an edit.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks, but what if all the tree Items are all of type='B' (which will result in no display of amounts, how do i hide all the zeroes "0" or any empty attributes created with the use of {}?

Comment: You can output them conditionally, using `<xsl:if test="$displayed-items">`.